# Deploy Symfony2 application to prod environment causes post-install-cmd exception

Tags: php, symfony, deployment, composer-php

I have read Symfony2 [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html) for **How to deploy a Symfony2 application** but I'm having some issues|warnings. As said [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html#c-update-your-vendors) the first command I run is this one:

```
composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
```

That command uninstall|erase `Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle` and I got this error at console:

```
Generating optimized autoload files
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle' not found in /var/www/sis-php-source/app/AppKernel.php on line 40
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/sis-php-source/app/console:0
PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /var/www/sis-php-source/app/console:28
PHP   3. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() /var/www/sis-php-source/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot() /var/www/sis-php-source/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:70
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles() /var/www/sis-php-source/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2343
PHP   6. AppKernel->registerBundles() /var/www/sis-php-source/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2513
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception

[RuntimeException]
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.
```

These are the contents of the files involved on this (`composer.json` and `AppKernel.php`)

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "Sis-PHP-Sources",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "Sis-PHP-Sources",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "~2.6",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "1.6.*@dev",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "0.13.*@dev",
        "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "2.7.*@dev",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.5.*@dev",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "2.4.*@dev",
        "knplabs/knp-menu": "2.0.*@dev",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "1.2.*@dev",
        "misd/phone-number-bundle": "~1.0",
        "willdurand/js-translation-bundle": "2.2.0",
        "vich/uploader-bundle": "1.0.*@dev",
        "javiereguiluz/easyadmin-bundle": "dev-master"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.6-dev"
        },
        "symfony-assets-install": "symlink"
    }
}
```

**AppKernel.php**

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle(),
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
            new FOS\JsRoutingBundle\FOSJsRoutingBundle(),
            new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),
            new Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle(),
            new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle(),
            new JMS\AopBundle\JMSAopBundle(),
            new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle(),
            new JMS\DiExtraBundle\JMSDiExtraBundle($this),
            new Misd\PhoneNumberBundle\MisdPhoneNumberBundle(),
            new Bazinga\Bundle\JsTranslationBundle\BazingaJsTranslationBundle(),
            new Vich\UploaderBundle\VichUploaderBundle(),
            new JavierEguiluz\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\EasyAdminBundle(),
            #Sis-PHP Bundles
            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
            new Sencamer\BackendBundle\BackendBundle(),
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__ . '/config/config_' . $this->getEnvironment() . '.yml');
    }

}
```

What I'm doing wrong? Is not that the right way to deploy a Symfony2 application? How I can fix that issue?

Comment: Could you add your `composer.json` file to the post?

Comment: @AndreySobkanyuk done, I've added the `composer.json` and also the `AppKernel.php`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have you read the info box on [the documentation page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html#c-update-your-vendors)?

> If you get a "class not found" error during this step, you may need to
>   run `export SYMFONY_ENV=prod` before running this command so that the
>   `post-install-cmd` scripts run in the `prod` environment.

Comment: Well, this is how my `AppKernel.php` file looks like, I didn't touch it on that lines, but as I said the issue is there, could you try to run that commands and tell me if you have the same problem? Perhaps is a issue or I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the issue and no I skip that box, my bad

Comment: @AndreySobkanyuk I don't think that's a good idea since the same issue would happen

Comment: @AndreySobkanyuk and again, that's neither necessary because `generator-bundle` means to be for `dev` environment

Comment: No worries mate ;) an extra set of eyes looking at the problem is always useful!